# Sync adapter , not visible in devtools--->sync tester

Tags: android

I created a sync adapter, which queries for dirty contacts, I want this to synchronise my existing exchange server account.

I think my problem is with syncadapter.xml

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
android:accountType="com.android.exchange"
android:supportsUploading="true"
android:userVisible="true" />
```

i don't want to create a new account as in google's sample sync adapter, I want my adapter to synchronise contacts with an existing corporate account.

Comment: Please explain more to get answer

Comment: when i created the exchange server account , it already has a sync adapter for syncing contacts . That adapter also has the same contentAuthority and accountType as my adapter , what i have to do to get my adapter visible in dev tools--->sync tester